# How to terminate a program started with ShellExecute

Tags: c++, windows, process, mfc, shellexecute

In MFC, I am using this code

```
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T(EXTERNAL_APP), params, 
             _T(EXTERNAL_PATH), SW_HIDE);
```

to start an external program which runs in the background.

However when my app is terminated , this program is still running, as can be verified by inspecting the Windows Task Manager pane.

So my question is, **how can I make the external program stop when my app stops** ?

Comment: Is the external application an application that you control, i.e. one whose source code you have access to? If so, I would suggest sharing an event between the two apps (pass the random name on the command line) that gets signaled when the external app needs to exit. This is the only clean way to ensure that the external app can cleanly shut down.

Comment: This can technically be done by using Job objects in Windows.  That however got screwed up in Vista, Explorer started putting processes in a job itself.  The simplest way is to just pass your PID to the started process through the command line and have it terminate when your process handle gets signaled.  Or kill it yourself, but that's without a guarantee.

Comment: No I have no access to the external app's source...

Comment: As @HansPassant said, job objects could have helped but yeah... Vista.  You will almost certainly have to use TerminateProcess; just be aware that can cause issues if you terminate the process while it's doing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ShellExecuteEx` instead, which can return a `HANDLE hProcess` of the newly-started process.

When/if you have a `HANDLE hProcess` then I expect you can pass it as a parameter it to the `TerminateProcess` function: which you would call (to terminate the child process) before your application stops.

Comment: While this will work, it can be *dangerous* to terminate another process - even one you launched - barring special insight into what process is doing at the time. Consider, for example, the effect a TerminateProcess will have if the process is in the middle of writing a configuration file to disk.